# Obtener la ruta de un archivo en onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-studio, fileupload

Tengo un problema al intentar obtener la ruta de un archivo, estoy haciendo uso de intent para seleccionar el documento que quiero y en el método **onActivityResult** intento recuperar la ruta usando **data.getData();**
pero lo que me recupera si imprimo el valor en la consola es una ruta como esta:

> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/884

El problema es que no se porque me devuelve una ruta como esta y el archivo no se llama 884

No he logrado hacer que me devuelva una ruta como esta:

> /storage/emulated/0/fname_1560529818711.jpg

Este es mi Intent:

```
public void subirDocumento(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona un archivo"), 4);
    }
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en mi metodo OnActivityResult:

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable final Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
if(requestCode == 4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri file = data.getData();
            Log.i("RING","Datos: "+file);

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                //Colocar un mensaje de espera mientras se suben los documentos
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File f  = new File(data.getDataString());
                    String content_type  = getMimeType(f.getPath());

                    String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);

                    RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                            .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                            .addFormDataPart("uploaded_file",file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("/")+1), file_body)
                            .build();

                    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                            .url("http://192.168.1.75/webServiceMGRex/save_file.php")
                            .post(request_body)
                            .build();

                    try {
                        okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                        if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                            throw new IOException("Error : "+response);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

            t.start();
        }
```

}

He intentado usar diferentes métodos como los siguientes pero no he logrado recuperar bien la ruta:

> Log.i("VALOR","Data: "+ data.getDataString());
>
> Log.i("INFO","Data:"+data.getData().getPath());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Crear metodo para obtener Path:

   ```
    public static String getPathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
   final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

   if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
       if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
           final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
           final String[] split = docId.split(":");
           final String type = split[0];

           if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
               return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
           }
       } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

           final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
           final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                   Long.valueOf(id));

           return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
       } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
           final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
           final String[] split = docId.split(":");
           final String type = split[0];

           Uri contentUri = null;
           if ("image".equals(type)) {
               contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
           } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
               contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
           } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
               contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
           }

           final String selection = "_id=?";
           final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { split[1] };

           return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
       }
   } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
       return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
   } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
       return uri.getPath();
   }

   return null;}                

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
   Cursor cursor = null;
   final String column = "_data";
   final String[] projection = { column };

   try {
       cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
       if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
           return cursor.getString(column_index);
       }
   } finally {
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.close();
   }
   return null;}         

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
   return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());}    

     public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
   return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());}        




      public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
   return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());}
   ```
2. Después en OnActivityResult:

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable final Intent data){

   ```
       Uri data = data.getData();
       if (data != null) {

           String filePath = getPathFromUri(this, data);
           Log.i("INFO", "FILE: " + filePath);

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Ever, gracias por tu aporte, como un consejo. Puedes mejorar tu respuesta detallando el por qué de cada punto que escribes, de igual forma el agregar ligas hacia otros recursos o la documentación oficial en partes específicas ayuda a entender mejor el **por qué de tu respuesta/solución**

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Ever, pero la solucion que me comentas me da un error, en el metodo onActivityResult al usar esta parte: String filePath = getPathFromUri(data), me da un error y me da la opcion de castear a String pero no funciona

Comment: @PakLei Muchas gracias.

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa faltó agregar el parámetro de contexto en el método String filePath = getPathFromUri(contexto, data)

Comment: @EverZevallos de echo si lo coloque de esa forma y me devuelve un valor null, ya verifique que mi data.getData() no llegue vació pero el metodo getPathFromUri me devuelve un null

Comment: @EverZevallos De echo si funciona pero solo con videos, no funciona para documentos eso me devuelve un null y las imagenes me crasean la app